# C++ multithreading today with a fluid situation for C++ 11 - book suggestions

Tags: c++, concurrency, c++11, pthreads, boost-thread

After a lot of searching and a bit of tries and failures, i have summed up things and this are the results:

- C++ 11 threading model it's not ready yet for GCC ( based on g++ 4.7 ) or Clang ( from the latest svn rev. ) - ( the 2 most up-to-date compilers out there ) - Clang doesn't even have a complete libcxx library yet, it's complete only for Mac OS.
- the standard threading library under C++ 11 it's really basic, for example the mutexes do not offer advanced features such as the "scoped based lock ( good for RAII )"  like `boost::thread` does
- `boost::thread` can be considered a wrapper, or an evolution if you will, of the Posix thread library, so in reality there isn't a real choice about threading libraries, they are not really that different, they are more like an evolution of the previous one.

Now I'm asking, if this is the scenario, where should I start ?

For example [this book](http://www.manning.com/williams/), is clearly oriented to the C++11 standard threading library, it gives you the basics but the one that you will probably never use in real life because the C++11 threading support is still not that good among the most popular compilers and it's really poor in terms of functionalities .

I think that it's fair to say that starting from `boost::thread` it's a good choice in the today's world - correct me if I'm wrong - and it's also the only real choice for both multi-platform support and legacy support for C++ 03: my problem is that I can't really find a book or a reference about concurrency and multithreading that looks just right or it's simply good enough for `boost:thread`.

Can you suggest a book for starting with concurrency and `boost::thread`?

Comment: For scope-based locking, there is [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) in C++11.

Comment: @jogojapan ah! strange namespace organization ... thanks for the tip by the way.

Comment: Keep in mind that the author of the book *C++ Concurrency in Action*, Anthony Williams, wrote the the boost threading library to follow as closely as possible to the C++11 proposals (which he also contributed to). C++11 threads and boost threads are *very* similar. You will still learn a lot from that book.

Comment: @SeanCline the problem is how much they are different, the problem is that the level of support for the C++ 11 will be probably really good 1 years from now and I start today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for a starter on boost threading take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415994/boost-thread-tutorials). Personally I started from [here](http://antonym.org/2009/05/threading-with-boost---part-i-creating-threads.html). And then of course there is the [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/thread.html).